# How to route HTTP and HTTPS to a CloudFront using Route 35 for a domain with no WWW and without using CNAME?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Let me describe my scenario, I have:

- EC2 instance (Wordpress)
- CloudFront distribution that serves the EC2 instance with **httpS** and redirects **http** to **httpS**.
- A `CNAME` AWS Route 53 record that points **www**.example.com to the CloudFront distribution.
- An `A` route 53 record that points root mydomain to EC2 IP.
- A lot of others Records  (MX, NS, SOA, TXT) in root mydomain.

[image]

What happens:

- ✅ Request **httpS**://**www**.example.com CloudFront serves content with AWS signed certificate.
- ✅ Request **http**://**www**.example.com CloudFront redirects to **httpS**://www.example.com.
- ✅ Request **http**://example.com (without www) my EC2 redirects to **httpS**://**www**.example.com
- ❌ Request **httpS**://example.com (without www), **Returns error** cause EC2 does not serve **httpS**

What can I do avoid this error.?

I was not able to add a `CNAME` record to root mydomain because `CNAME` cannot co-exist with another records (MX, NS, SOA, TXT)

I was not able to route the `A` record to CloudFront because I do not found an `IP` for CloudFront distibution and probably there is no `IP` address.

Comment: You need to configure your EC2 instance to serve https. (yes, you need proper cert even only to respond with redirect).

Comment: Or maybe create ALIAS record for root domain, instead of CNAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `naked` domain (`example.com`) use a Route 53 Record Set with the type `A` and enable the `Alias` option. Then specify the CloudFront distribution as the `Alias Target`. Logically this is very similar to setting up a CNAME.

[Routing Traffic to an Amazon CloudFront Web Distribution by Using Your Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)